# A simple (Partial) Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I had ode and pde quite while ago but need it now again for a physics calls so I would be grateful for your help here.

Give the differential equation:
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x)+\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=6f(x)
$$

a) This is a second order, homogenous ordinary differential equation right?
b) I also did manage to get the solutions but a question is: "What would happen if constant is added in the differential equation?". The de would be inhomogeneous right? But what would change for the general solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: also, this isn't a pde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) yes, this is a second order, homogeneous and linear ordinary differential equation with constant coefficients.
b) Solutions to inhomogeneous linear diffeq's are given by a sum of the homogeneous solution, and a particular one.

I.e., if you want to solve 
$$
f''(x)+f'(x)-6f(x)=C
$$
then you can ansatz a polynomial solution to find $C/2x^2$ is a particular solution, making your general solution
$$
f(x)=c_1e^{2x}+c_2e^{-3x}+C/2x^2
$$